# can't add folder in git

Tags: git

I add new folder (actually I cloned it from another repo, and forgot that), then I did some changes there. Additionally I did a lot of changes in another places, when I tried to do git add

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   protected/ext/SpecificFolder (modified content)
#
```

Then I remember that maybe there was .git folder (because previous I did git clone there).
I went to that folder and remove non needed files (folders) and .git folder too.
I checked git status, nothing strange. Then commit and checkout to another branch and suddenly I figure out that this folder was not added to last commit. Actually folder was added but files inside was ignored. Now even when I'm trying to do `git add` for that folder nothing happenning and `git status` do not show any changes :(

What can I do ?

Comment: In case anyone else ends up on this page with the problem I faced: I wasn't able to add files in a sub-folder to Git. Later I found that that sub-folder had its own `.git` repository and files were getting added to that repository instead of the repository in the main folder. Even in the Git GUI, that sub-folder appeared as a file instead of as a folder.

Comment: This exact problem has happened to me and it's very frustrating. There is an empty folder on GitHub, I didn't even know that was possible.

Answer (score 47):

Git doesn't track directories; but just the files within them.

It sounds like you might have an ignore pattern that is causing `add` to do nothing.  You can see ignored files with `git status --ignored`; they can then be tracked with `git add --force protected/ext/SpecificFolder`

Comment: No it's not presen in `git status --ignored`, somehow I'm thinking it is connected with submodule

Comment: This command was a life-saver.  Without it, I would've never figured out which directory was ignored.

Comment: wow..... I felt totally stupid reading this fact after using git for some time now ^^

Comment: Aha, finally. This was my problem. I had copied .gitignore from parent and into submodules. I was ignoring 'config/' and later I created a directory under source dir named config. Could not add of cource. Problem solved now thank you :-)

Comment: cool ,save my time

Answer (score 11):

Git doesn't track EMPTY directories. If you have a project w/ multiple layers of subdirectories, git does in fact track the directories w/ files in them. If it didn't, then it would be one flat repository of files.

Comment: Wow this is such a simple thing but damn. I read this and went "oh my God that's exactly it"

Answer (score 8):

I happened to do exactly what this user did: Add an existing git repository inside another one.

The symptom was that git recognised that directory as a file, and thus was unable to add the directory's files.

To solve that question, I deleted the `.git` folder in the folder, moved that folder in another directory, cleared the index, removed the directory where in my repo, and then I was able to add the directory properly.

The moral of this is: don't add a repository inside another one.

Comment: It can also be fixed by running `git rm --cached path_to_submodule`

Comment: VictorMarchuk this solved my problem after I deleted the `.git` directory

Comment: @VictorMarchuk This solved my problem!!

Comment: @VictorMarchuk that should be the answer to this question. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There is a better answer here:
[.gitkeep usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229885/what-are-the-differences-between-gitignore-and-gitkeep)

TL;DR, add a `.gitkeep` file to your empty directory

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a file in that directory.

```
$ git add my-dir/index.html
```

If you see a output like the below:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
my-dir/index.html
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

There's a rule in one of your gitignores that prevent you from adding that directory.

Answer (score 0):

I found similar side-effects after trying to convert what used to be a submodule into a normal subfolder.

Re-adding the folder I was attempting to convert seemed to work, but it turns out that the files inside it were not actually added.

Trying to specifically add a file inside it gave me a better warning

```
git add sites/all/modules/contrib/transclusion/transclusion.module 
fatal: Pathspec 'sites/all/modules/contrib/transclusion/transclusion.module' is in submodule 'sites/all/modules/contrib/transclusion'
```

- so it was related to the way I had manually tried to remove the old submodule, as there was no well-documented process for doing it properly. - I had just deleted it from .gitmodules. Other stuff was actually necessary to eraticate the shadows of the submodule.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem while working on a new get repository.
Attempting to add a specific folder, I encountered a fatal error, with no useful information. Other folders did not lead to such a problem.
After some tinkering, I found that I had a .git file in this folder. I removed it, then attempted to add the folder again. This time it worked as it should.
I then made a change in a single file, and tried to update my repository. Got a message recommending condensing multiple loose object. I first tried to update the repository and failed. Then I opted for condensing the repository database, and followed updating the repository. This time it worked!